# Magento: How to add color.js to custom Module Sytstem configruation settings

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have created  theme module. i want user to choose color of font. for that i want to have color.js not a textfield for html code.

is there any way to add color.js in magento system/cofig of our module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the JS file somewhere into the "js" folder, and in the XML layout you can include it with:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>folder/color.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

Hope that helps.

Also You can also do it in your block:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('path/from/js/your_folder/color.js');

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

hope this will help to you.

Comment: @Jack Torris, glad to help you.